# Where should properties reside when modeling OOP? Small example included

Tags: c#, oop, interface, abstract-class

I'm looking to learn how to use interfaces and base classes effectively. I'm not exactly sure where to put common properties? Do only behaviors belong in an interface? If properties such as: Color and MinSpeed shouldn't go in the interface, where should they live? In an abstract class?

```
public interface IVehicle
{
    void Speed();
    void Clean();
    void Stop();
}

public class Bmw : IVehicle
{
    // Because these pertain to every vehicle no matter of maker,
    // should these propertes go in the interface? Or in an abstract class?
    public string Color { get; set; }
    public int MinSpeed { get; set; }

    #region IVehicle Members

    public void Speed()
    {

    }

    public void Clean()
    {

    }

    public void Stop()
    {

    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: Note that properties _are_ behavior, as a property is a getter/setter.  There is no obligation that a property actually 'contain' data, though there is a strong expectation that getting/setting a property behaves in a 'data-like' way.  The real question here is what needs access to the behavior of changing these properties; think about the expected use-cases for your interface and that will give you an idea of whether it makes sense to expose 'property data' through the interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interfaces can be thought of as a contract that must be satisfied by any implementing class.  Use it if you want to guarentee that all classes do the same thing—satisfy the same API—but you don't care *how* they do it.  **If properties are a part of that API, then by all means include them in your interface**.

From your example above, if you want all cars to be **guaranteed** to have a color and minSpeed, then those properties belong in the interface.  If those properties are specific to BMWs alone, then they belong in the BMW class.  If those properties belong to some classes but not others, you could create a new interface extending the original one:

```
public interface IVehicleWithColorAndMinSpeed : IVehicle
{
    string Color { get; set; }
    int MinSpeed { get; set; }
}
```

<sub>(just don't get carried away with this)</sub>

---

Abstract classes are similar, but allow you to provide a default implementation for your sub classes.

Abstract classes tend to be easier to version, since you can add something new to your API, and provide a default implementation that your existing subclasses will automatically pick up;  adding something to an interface immediately breaks all existing classes which implement that interface.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Head is still trying to put it all together. Thinking of what to do if I wanted to set a default color for all vehicles to red.

Comment: @Frankie - you could look at a factory method for that.  That's just one possible way; there are lots of others.

Comment: The factory would essentially give me back a BMW object with the color set to "red"? IVehicle bmw = Factory.GetBMW();

Comment: @Frankie - you have many options.  `Factory.GetRedBmw();`  `Factory.GetBmwByColor(Color.Red);` and so on

Answer (score 0):

The 'right' answer is entirely dependent on your domain model. What is the problem you're trying to solve? There is no 'right' answer other than the one which solves the particular problem at hand with the greatest:

- understandability
- maintainability
- brevity
- isolation
- performance

You can probably consider most of those properties to be in order of importance, but they mean different things to different people and there's probably a lot of debate implied there too.

Can you tell us any more about the particular application you imagine these classes to serve?